# Temporarily store SQLite Database rows before write back to it

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a scenario, whereby my App-A needs to read the Data from Database of App-B.
1) Modify the App-B's DB
2) Remove some rows of Data & save it.
3) While App-A is getting killed, restore App-B's data.

Now my concern is what's best way to save App-B's DB data so that it can easily be restored ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you getting data from App B first and storing it into an Array of ItemData.class you have created. (Do this using your code in app A.)

ItemData.class :

```
public class ItemData{
public int itemId;
public String itemText;
public boolean itemBoolean;
}
```

And  you can add new Item to your array as below:

```
ArrayList<ItemData> items= new ArrayList<>();
ItemData item = new ItemData();
item.itemId = //you should assign id from app b database
item.itemText = //you should assign text from app b database
item.itemBoolean = //you should assign boolean from app b database
items.add(item);
```

Then you can access all the data from app be and modify them meanwhile they are available. This will be much faster and data will not get lost from your array.

Now with a for loop you can restore all data and save it on another database:

```
for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        int restoredID = items.get(i).itemId;
        String restoredString = items.get(i).itemText;
        boolean restoredBoolean  = items.get(i).itemBoolean;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggest @Lord Tesla , I will give it a go to check, seems OK for my case.

Comment: If this helped don't forget to up vote my answer. I would appreciate it.

Comment: @ Lord Tesla, can we save Cursor object retrieved from APP-B's DB directly & use it to populate the data back ? Any particular reason to store data to Array first ?

Comment: thanks for suggestion. It works fine. Using cursor is not good enough because it's just a reference to the DB, so once DB is updated, cursor object is also updated. So cannot be reused.

Comment: Whenever you need a little a bit of persistence to keep some thing to decide the next process from, you can also add an other array list of itemsTemp and use it for processing and updating items array list which is the updated list and keep itemsTemp untouched.